# How to select rows without duplicates and partition only by some columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a `SELECT` that neglects duplicates. The duplicates should be detected by only some columns, while I still want to select all columns of one row.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE employee ( 
    id integer,
    firstname varchar(100), 
    lastname varchar(100), 
    country varchar(100), 
    salary interger,
    //many more fields...
);
    
select * from employee GROUP BY firstname, lastname, country;
```

Of course that's invalid sql, but it shows my intention:

If any combination of (firstname, lastname, country) forms a duplicate key, then I only want to select **one** of those duplicate rows, but **all** columns of it.

Preferably, out of the duplicates I would want to select the row with the highest value in `salary` column.

I'm using `mysql 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to do this. Essentially what you have posted for your grouping instead becomes your partition, and you can then chose how each group is sorted (in the case of the below `salary`):

```
select *
from (select *, 
             row_number() over(partition by firstname, lastname, country 
                               order by salary desc) AS rownum
      from employee) AS e
where e.rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to select unique combinations of firstname, lastname, country:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, country order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want one row only where there are duplicates, then include a `count()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, country order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by firstname, lastname, country) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and cnt > 1;
```